# Query about preposition

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I'll show you a sentence below:

> I learned about American history in middle school.

In the clause, you can see the preposition of 'in'.

What is the correct definition of 'in' in the above sentence?

1) At the point within an area or a space
2) Involved in something ; taking part in something

A source of 'In' from: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/in_1?q=in

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence, "in" is being used as a preposition to describe when it happened.

Definition number 5 from the link you provided is the one you're wanting:

> 5. during a period of time

Comment: What about this sentence? 'I have a bachelor's degree in English education.' In that, I think that it is two possible answer. First, Involved in sth or taking part in. Second, to show somebody's job or profession. What do you think?

Comment: @bak1936 *15) concerning something* It's describing the *bachelor's degree* (what it's concerned with); it's not saying anything about *you*.

Comment: Thanks! I need more practice and training. It is very confusing to me, and there are a lot of definition.

Comment: one more question! Preposition 'in' is used in many situation. I saw it simply. activity, time, subject, on person's body, opinion, etc. in all way it can be used. You gave me any answer. By the way, is it correct? In your answer, the meaning seems to be correct. Can it be being used in going side by side? Could you understand what I mean? I just wonder it!!

Comment: For example, He was taken to the hospital during the night. During say generally a period of time. It doesn't seem to be any problems even in tense.

Comment: @bak1936 Please post another question if you have follow ups.  Accept my answer if it answered your posted question.